The name "Maj Kmetic" has an emtpy first name when using the nameparser library in python
I already made an issue about this on the nameparser github page but it looked kind of "Inactive", so I wanted to try and ask this question here. 
When I parse the name "Maj Kmetic" and I want to retrieve the first name and the surnames, the first name is empty.
Code:
from nameparser import HumanName

name = HumanName('Maj Kmetic')
print(f"First: {name.first}")
print(f"Last: {name.surnames}")

Output:
First: 
Last: Kmetic

But when I use the names: "Ma Kmetic" and "Maji Kmetic" the first name isn't empty:
Outputs:
First: Ma
Last: Kmetic

--- AND ---

First: Maji
Last: Kmetic

In general the first name "Maj" seems to be the problem, changing the last name doesn't seem to have any affect on the general outcome.

Did you look at the other attributes of name? Maybe it's interpreted as a title, for example (update: yes, it is); we can't really help you with a random third party library.

You're completely right, my bad. The first name "Maj" is seen as a title probably because it's seen as "Major"

related read: Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names

"Major" seems a reasonable guess as the list also includes "majgen" -> "major general", but HumanName('Major Kmetic') thinks Major is the first name.

The library in question treats the string Maj as a formal title (ostensibly “Major”); see nameparser/config/titles.py:L383.
According to the documentation, you can remove this string from consideration as a title (and instead parse it as part of the name) by calling:
from nameparser.config import CONSTANTS

CONSTANTS.titles.remove('Maj')

